# Clicking Drawn Checkboxs

Tags: c#, checkbox, mouseevent

I have a listview with a number of drawn checkboxs in it.

Currently when I click the drawn checkbox on the listview it either clicks the first check box in that column or nothing at all.

I have know it has something to do with the temppoint, so after I post this hopefully I can come to the solution myself before someone answers :P.

This is where the checkbox is drawn

```
private void lstSourceToUser_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex > 1)
    {
        int usrIndex = userProfile.GetUserIndexByID(e.Header.Name);
        int srcIndex = userProfile.GetUsersSourceIndex(e.Header.Name, e.Item.SubItems[0].Text);
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(g,new Point((e.Bounds.X + e.Bounds.Width/2 -10 ),(e.Bounds.Y)), userProfile.SystemUserList[usrIndex].fusionUserSources[srcIndex].UserSourceChkBox.MyCheckedState ? CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal : CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
    }
    else
        // Draw the other subitems with default drawing.
        e.DrawDefault = true;
}
```

And this is where the click event happens

```
private void lstSourceToUser_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem = lstSourceToUser.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).SubItem;
    if (subItem.Name != "")
    {
        Point tempPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        int userIndex = userProfile.GetUserIndexByName(subItem.Name);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(subItem.Bounds.X, subItem.Bounds.Y, 100, subItem.Bounds.Height);
        if (rect.Contains(tempPoint))
        {
            int srcIndex = userProfile.GetUserSourceIndexByUserName(subItem.Name, lstSourceToUser.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text);
            userProfile.SystemUserList[userIndex].fusionUserSources[srcIndex].UserSourceChkBox.MyCheckedState = !userProfile.SystemUserList[userIndex].fusionUserSources[srcIndex].UserSourceChkBox.MyCheckedState;
            this.lstSourceToUser.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated be it solutions or links/guides :)
Thank you

Comment: Do check if the `subItem.Bounds.Y` are reporting the correct y-position for all items!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't the tempPoint it was srcIndex.

```
if (rect.Contains(tempPoint))
    {
        **int srcIndex = userProfile.GetUserSourceIndexByUserName(subItem.Name, lstSourceToUser.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text);**
        userProfile.SystemUserList[userIndex].fusionUserSources[srcIndex].UserSourceChkBox.MyCheckedState = !userProfile.SystemUserList[userIndex].fusionUserSources[srcIndex].UserSourceChkBox.MyCheckedState;
        this.lstSourceToUser.Invalidate();
    }
```

---

```
public int GetUserSourceIndexByUserName(string userName, string sourceId)
    {
        foreach (FCMUser user in SystemUserList)
        {
            if (**user.id** != userName) continue;
            var index = 0;
            foreach (FCMSource src in user.fusionUserSources)
            {
                if (src.id == sourceId)
                {
                    return index;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The if statement looking for the match userName was incorrect. It was checking User ID not User Name.

Silly Mistake from me. Live and Learn I guess.